# Executing Excel Workbook via Shortcuts or from the Directory is Causing Problems in Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, office365, excel-2016

In the **Windows 7 and Office 360 with Excel v.10** I created an Excel Workbook.
 The **Workbook has a Form**. When the **Form loads the VBA makes the Workbook invisible** by the command ***Application.Visible = False***; so, **only the Form is seen**. If I execute the Workbook via the Shortcut, clicking it in the Directory, in the VBA editor or from within Excel (click Open then double-click the Workbook name), the Form stays visible and the Workbook disappears. Perfect!
Then, we **upgraded to Windows 10 and Office 365 with Excel v.16**.
 Now, when I **execute the Workbook from the Shortcut or clicking it in its Directory**, the **Form opens but the Workbook remains VISIBLE!**
 
If I execute the Workbook from the VBA editor or from within Excel, **the Workbook disappears just like before**.
So, there's a problem with the **Excel Shortcuts or clicking on it in its directory? Is there a fix?**
The Code below is the initial code that opens the Form. Thanks for any help!

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .CalculateBeforeSave = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    'Password Protect WorkSheet
    With MainForm
        .Label3 = "Program Name"
        .ProgToRun.Text = Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("A2")
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Select
        .Label1 = "Choose a program to run from drop-down menu." & vbCr & _
        "Then, click the " & """Run Selection""" & " button."
        .Label2 = ""
        .BttnYES.Visible = False
        .BttnNO.Visible = False
        .BttnRun.SetFocus
        .Show vbModeless
    End With
    Application.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code of the `Workbook_Open` event and how the form is loaded, or better provide a [mcve] to reproduce that issue. Without a code that reproduces the issue it is hard to help. • Are macros automatically enabled when opening that workbook? Does the `Workbook_Open` event even run automatically if you start it from the directory?

Comment: OK I added code

Comment: "Does the Workbook_Open event even run automatically if you start it from the directory?" Well, if I put a Msgbox in  the Workbook_Open Event and click from the directory it give the message; so, yes, I assume it is being executed.